# How to validate file data from HDFS and Hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, bigdata, oracle-golden-gate

I have Requirement in my current project, I am retrieving  data from Oracle source Database and load in to HDFS destination directory as a CSV file through Oracle goldengate data replication. 
Each job execution,I need to validate the data from HDFS and Hive table that is accurate and consistent. What will be the best way to do this? Please let me know.

Comment: what would you want to reconcile, the Hive table or the HDFS files?

Comment: need to reconcile in csv file from HDFS directory and hive table. it is full load

Comment: This smells like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me. What are you actually trying to do here?